# Set the 'start-interval' of a healthcheck in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, health-check, docker-healthcheck

I am deploying some services using Docker Compose. I want to check that my containers are healthy using `healthcheck` (see Docker Compose documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck)).

Let's consider the following code. It works fine, except when I uncomment the last line:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3.8"

services:
  postgres:    # this is just an example, please don't focus on that particular image
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -d my_db -U my_user    # again, the command here is not my point, nor the env, feel free to change it
      interval: 60s
      start_period: 30s
      # start_interval: 5s # → this line is commented because it raises an error! Why?
```

[This page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) of the Dockerfile documentation describes the difference between various settings in the `HEALTHCHECK` instruction. It details the difference between the option `interval` and the option `start-interval`.

Uncommenting the last line would raise the following exception, but why? Admittedly, I haven't seen `start_interval` mentioned in the Docker Compose doc, it just felt intuitive...

```
validating /my_path/docker-compose.yml: services.postgres.healthcheck Additional property start_interval is not allowed
```

The `start_period` option has been added in file format 3.4 ([release note](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-34)). Am I right assuming that `start_interval` hasn't been introduced and cannot be parsed by Docker Compose yet? Am I the only one needing this feature?

Any alternative solution? My `docker-compose.yml` gathers many services that I want to `healthcheck`. I'd like to avoid having a `Dockerfile` for each of them: wherever possible, I lean on environment variables to custom default images and I'm simply putting the `healthcheck` instructions in my `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answering my own question for future readers.

This is a new feature in Docker Compose. It has already been implemented but a few days ago. I was definitely not the only one frustrated by this lack!

[Here](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/pull/383) is the corresponding pull request which has been merged and released ([release note of `compose-go`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/releases/tag/v1.17.0) and [release note of `docker compose`](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases)).

Thus, updating my version of `Docker Compose` to `v2.20.2` fixed the issue.

Comment: I am not getting the `start_*` settings to work. I am using the latest version of docker compose (v2.20.2-desktop.1), and I am using `start_period: 10s` and `start_interval: 1s`. My app has about a 5s bootstrapping period before the server starts. My hope is that for the first 10s, the healthcheck should happen every 1s. However, the server starts listening after about 5s, and then it just sits there for about 15s before anything else happens.

Comment: probably it will not work until engine [25.0.0](https://github.com/moby/moby/milestone/119) is released, it contains [a tracking issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/45897) for `start_interval`

Comment: Currently, Docker is past 25 but Docker Compose isn't. I wonder if the support is there (Win+WSL): `docker --version
Docker version 25.0.2, build 29cf629` and `docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.24.3-desktop.1`.

Comment: Works in: Docker Compose version v2.24.5-desktop.1